# How can I dynamically change the data in a table depending on search results?

Tags: php, mysql, search, dynamic

I am trying to build a page that displays the data that has been searched for within a html table. I have the search field and button set up on the page and a small table showing all data currently. I need it to actively change the data displayed in the table depending on the words in the search field.

EDIT:

How can I dynamically change the data within the table depending on the text in the search field?

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database name";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT clientname, clientsurname, address1, postcode, dob FROM clients";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Address</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Date of Birth</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["clientname"]."</td><td>".$row["clientsurname"]."</td><td>".$row["address1"]."</td><td>".$row["postcode"]."</td><td>".$row["dob"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "There are 0 clients in the system matching your search criteria";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you have a queston?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the final line, will edit post now and update. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Take a look at ajax and jquery..

Comment: Take a look at MVC pattern first, will save lot of time in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @eselskas said + If you want to search by the given value from your search bar, you need to change the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT clientname, clientsurname, address1, postcode, dob FROM `clients` WHERE `your_field` LIKE '%$_POST[search_var]%'";
```

or better:

```
if($_POST['change_var'] != ""){
   $sql = "SELECT clientname, clientsurname, address1, postcode, dob FROM `clients` WHERE `your_field` LIKE '%$_POST[search_var]%'";
}else{
   $sql = "SELECT clientname, clientsurname, address1, postcode, dob FROM `clients`";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create an ajax request to the back-end, searching the database and returning a json response which would be appended into your html.

This however would require your code to be re-factored and split the front-end and back-end logic.